# How to get a different output from the csv with every click and not the final line?

Tags: java, csv, android-studio

Hello I have wrote this code to read my csv and when I click a button I get an output. The thing is the only line that gets printed is the final row of the csv. How can I modify my code so with each and every click I get next line?
``InputStream inputStream;
String[] ids;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dating);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try{
                String csvLine;
                while((csvLine = reader.readLine())!=null){

                    ids = csvLine.split(",");
                    try{
                        textView.setText(ids[3]+ids[4]);


                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e("Unknown exception", e.toString());
                    }




                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the:

```
inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dating);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

out off the OnClickListener.
That's all.